# NSURL with subdirectory path

Tags: ios, nsurl, nsbundle

I have the following code that works fine but only when the file is in the project root directory:

```
NSURL *soundFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                       URLForResource:@"coffeeshop"
                       withExtension:@"mp3"
                       //subdirectory:@"data/audio"
                       ];
```

I am trying to put the file in the subdirectory `data/audio` by uncommenting the code above but it stops working and when I do an `NSLog(@"Output: %@",soundFileURL);` I get `Output: (null)`

Comment: This will only work if the mp3 file is really installed in the "data/audio" subfolder in the .app. Make sure in your project, the "data" and "audio" folders are blue and not yellow.

Comment: @maddy how do you make them blue?

Answer (score 0):

If you have resources added to your project you need to know if you added them into the project or added them as references to files (and folders).  If you added them to the project without adding them as reference then any files and folders will be flattened down to the main bundle fonder.  If they are added by reference then you can access them in their existing folder structure (like you want).

If you want to access them via folders and subfolders then you need to make sure to add the resources to the project using the option "Create folder references for an added folders".

If you already have them added into your project and want to change the way they are references the easiest way is to delete them from the project tree and re drag and drop them into the project.  You will get an option window with options for how to add them (reference or not) and what targets to add them to.